# Jest - mock individual function from es6 class

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, es6-class

I would like to test whether a particular function is called from the function I'm testing however both of these functions are within the es6 class I am testing.

Setup:

// MyClass.js

```
export default class MyClass {
   constructor () { ... }
   foo() {
      ...
      bar()
   }
   bar() { 
      ... 
   }
}
```

So I am testing foo() but as part of my test I want to ensure that bar() is called. I can see how I can do this if bar() was an external dependency as I could just mock that but as it's part of the class I am testing I can't mock the entire class otherwise I wouldn't be calling a concrete implementation in my test.

I was hoping this would've done the trick (as per https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/es6-class-mocks.html) but to no avail:

// MyClass.spec.js

```
jest.unmock('./MyClass')
import MyClass from './MyClass'  
...
test('my test', () => {
   var mockBar = jest.fn()
   MyClass.bar = mockBar   

   var myClass = new MyClass()
   myClass.foo()

   expect(mockBar).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

I also tried mocking the method on the instantiated version of MyClass (i.e. myClass.bar = mockBar) but neither gave the desired results.

Is this mocking structure possible with jest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When testing specific method of ES6 class (not class instance) you should mock not the property of the class, but property of this class *prototype*.

```
jest.unmock('./MyClass')
import MyClass from './MyClass'  
...
test('my test', () => {
  var mockBar = jest.fn()
  MyClass.prototype.bar = mockBar // here's the difference   

  var myClass = new MyClass()
  myClass.foo()

  expect(mockBar).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

This is because ES6 classes is just sugar over plain Javascript prototype model, and

```
class MyClass {
  bar() {}
}
```

is equivalent not to

```
var MyClass = function () {
  MyClass.bar = function bar() {};

  return MyClass;
}();
```

but to

```
var MyClass = function () {
  MyClass.prototype.bar = function bar() {};

  return MyClass;
}();
```